# Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed

I'm having trouble while making a test with my website (http://prorako.com) . You can try this here :

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr&url=prorako.com

The desktop version return an error code 500 but the mobile is correct.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is working properly both mobile and desktop are returning results. Check Again and run the optimization link. Clear your cache and check again

Comment: Does your site returns 500 internal server error while loading? try opening the page optimization link in incognito tab and check !!